# Automatically Update the package.json in NodeJS application

Tags: node.js, dependencies, package.json

I have created the package.json using npm init. After some stage I installed few more modules as per the need.Rather than updating the package.json dependencies manually, is there any way to automatically update it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking correctly, you want to use npm to install a dependency and have that dependency automatically added to your `package.json` ?

If so, use `--save` after the package name :

```
npm install [package name] --save
```

Answer (score 0):

For download the all packages configured in the `package.json`, use:

`npm update --save`

Docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update